# Appending a variable using ParamSpec to type mock.patch?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to type a decorator factory and it seems to require appending something to a `ParamSpec` rather than prepending it:

```py
P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

def patch_clients(*targets: str):
    def decorator(func: Callable[Concatenate[P, ClientsMock], R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
        clients_mock = ClientsMock()
        for target in targets:
            func = mock.patch(target, clients_mock)(func)

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            return func(*args, clients_mock, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Usage:

```py
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch_client('some.module.import')
    def test_foo(self, clients_mock):
        pass
```

This doesn't work as the last argument to `Concatenate` needs to be `P`. However, I can't pass `clients_mock` as the first argument to `func` as that would mess with `self` at the use site (`test_foo()`) of the decorator.

Is there a way to achieve the type of `test_foo()` that I want?

Comment: Can you pass `mock` as always 2nd argument, so it's `Callable[Concatenate[object, Mock, _P], _R]`? Return type will be `Callable[Concatenate[object, _P], _R]`. Not sure that `object` will be acceptable for mypy, if not - use `Any` instead of return type.